# Customize a SQL-query to check column from GET-Request

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jersey, request

I have a table with 5 columns:

**Table**

```
id----A-----B------C-----D-----E------F
1-----32----789----65----21----56-----25
2-----34----54-----45----90----34-----96
3-----10----56-----78----56----90-----45
```

I got a query with the 5 columns and I have to search in the database. But I don't know which column the user could want

```
public Response getColum(
            @QueryParam("a") short a, @QueryParam("b") short b,
            @QueryParam("c") short c,
            @QueryParam("d") short d,
            @QueryParam("e") short e) {
...
```

**in my SQL-Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM Table where a = ? AND b = ?
```

One alternativ is to check the different case, but too expensive.

How can I customize my query when I can not know which column the user could request? I don't want to build a IF-Statements, there are too many different cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.  You have a jersey resource with parameters a,b,c,d, and e, which seem to correspond to the first 5 columns of the table you listed... I don't understand what you're trying to do or what the issue is.  What different "cases" are you talking about?

Comment: to understand correctly: you have 5 possible filters on your table (on 5 columns) and you might receive 1,2,...up to 5 filter values on the request, however you do not know which and you have to construct the SQL dynamically.

Comment: Your table has got 6 columns (without id).

Comment: Can the user only select one column (a to e), or is it possible to query multiple columns (e.g. a, b and e) too?

Comment: it is possible to query multiple columns (a&b, a&b&c or c&d&e). And i don't know which one!!!!

Comment: If I understood correctly, in order to compose your query you only need 5 if-statements. You start composing your query like `SELECT * FROM Table where`, if the 1st parameter is informed, you add `a = ?`, if the 2nd parameter is informed, you add `b = ?` or `and b = ?`, etc. Finally you inform the variables and that's it. You don't have to check every possible combination, you just compose your query iteratively. Hope is helps.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be instead of putting all QueryParams in the method parameters and not know which one has received values, you could just inject UriInfo object using @Context annotation and then you can have:

```
MultiValuedMap<String,String> params = uriInfo.getQueryParameters()
```

which will contain only the parameters send. then you can iterate through this map, and just dynamically create WHERE criteria which is added using a StringBuilder to the basic statement "SELECT * FROM TABLE", due to the fact that the key is the filter name (aka column name) and the value is the filter value.

Comment: The problem isn't the method parameters, but how can i customize the query? there are too many different cases. The user can request multiple columns and i don't know which one. I only know, there are this and this column, but which one in the query?

Comment: you customize the query only by generating the statement dinamically, based on the query parameters send. Now, in order to avoid checking which parameters have been sent, using what the approach described, you will have in the Map received only the query parameters the user is interested in. And by iterating through them you can dynamically generate the final SQL statement.